# Including .dSYM file inside .ipa file

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, ipa, dsym

For iOS builds with Xcode 8, is it possible to include a generated .dSYM file into the .ipa file?

I'm building my ipa files like this (in Jenkins but it shouldn't matter) ...

```
# Create xarchive
xcodebuild
    -workspace /sourcepath/myapp.xcworkspace
    -sdk iphoneos
    -scheme 'Distribution Production'
    -configuration 'Distribution Production'
    -archivePath '/outputpath/Distribution Production-iphoneos/myapp.xcarchive'
    'CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=********'
    'PROVISIONING_PROFILE=App Enterprise PRD'
    DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT=dwarf-with-dsym
    archive

# Create IPA
xcodebuild
    -exportArchive
    -archivePath '/outputpath/Distribution Production-iphoneos/myapp.xcarchive'
    -exportOptionsPlist '/outputpath/Distribution Production-iphoneos/export_options.plist'
    -exportPath '/outputpath/Distribution Production-iphoneos'
```

This generates an xarchive and lastly an ipa file. The xarchive then contains the .dSYM file but I'd like to have the .dSYM in the IPA file instead. Is this possible?

I tried using these arguments in addition when creating the xarchive:

```
'DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH=/outputpath/Distribution Production-iphoneos'
'DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME=Distribution Production.dSYM'
```

... but then the xarchive doesn't contain the dSYM and it isn't being found anywhere else.

Comment: did you manage to figure this one out? having same issue with xcframework